# Android - publish permission declined

Tags: android, facebook

After long struggle to grant publish permission (publish_actions) they declined my request with this message

[image]

Your app uses a social plugin or share dialog to share content to Facebook. These don't need write permissions and don't need to be submitted for review. Our sharing docs have more information, and you can find the most up-to-date plugin versions here.

here is my code I am using to publish , I am using shareDialog , but I dont know how to share without it , any one could help me

```
mShareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

public void publishStory(String Scontent) {
        AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (token == null) {
            LoginWithPublishPermission();
            return;
        }
        Set<String> permissions = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            Log.d("FB TAG", "facebook publish permission login");
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            LoginWithPublishPermission();
            return;
        }


        if (mShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(AppURL))
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.share_from_leaynik))
                    .setContentDescription(Scontent)
                    .build();

            mShareDialog.show(content);
        } else {
            try {
                String sharerUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + AppURL;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

    private void LoginWithPublishPermission() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(Disease_Details.this, PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS);
    }
```

Comment: The Share dialog doesn’t need any permissions.

Comment: thanks for answer but how can I asking for permission if its not granted

Comment: You don’t _need_ any permission to use the Share dialog – so stop _asking_ for that permission in your code.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation is Facebook is asking you to use normal sharing mechanism instead of publish direction to the Facebook post through `publish_actions` Facebook is quite strict of what could be automatically publish to it's posting automatically without the User manual intervention.

So my recommendation is remove the `publish_actions` from your facebook permission requested. Use the normal sharing function as below instead :-

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "YOUR MESSAGE TITLE");
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR MESSAGE");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Sharing the App"));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What error was it showing? I copy and paste from a real code in an active app.